# regarding scope of variable in C

Tags: c, scope

```
#include<stdio.h>
int countdigits(int n);
int main(void)
{
   int t,k;
   scanf("%d %d",&t,&k);

   long long N[t];
   int i;

   for (i=0;i<t;i++)
   {

       scanf("%lld",&N[i]);
   }

int j,main_count=0;
for (j=0;j<t;j++)
{

    int counter=0;
    while (N[j] !=0)
    {

        if (N[j]%10 <=k)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
            ;
        N[j]=N[j]/10;
    }
        if (counter==countdigits(N[j]))
            main_count+=1;

}
   printf("%d",main_count);

    return 0;
}

int countdigits(int n)
{
    int num,counter=0;
    num=n;
    for(;num !=0;num=num/10)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

i am sure about the algo , the question is here
Let's call a number k-good if it contains all digits not exceeding k (0, ..., k).
You've got a number k and an array a containing n numbers.
Find out how many k-good numbers are in a (count each number every time it occurs in array a).

**Input**
The first line contains integers n and k (1 ≤ n ≤ 100, 0 ≤ k ≤ 9). The i-th of the following n lines contains integer ai without leading zeroes (1 ≤ ai ≤ 109).

**Output**
Print a single integer — the number of k-good numbers in a.

can somebody tell me where am i going wrong ?

Comment: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/365/A

Comment: Which variable's scope are you worried about?

Comment: 2nd sample output is 1 how?!

Comment: Why read all of the numbers into an array? (Are you allowed to dynamically allocate arrays like that? Maybe I'm out-of-date) Why not just process them as you read them in?

Comment: @Hasan if k=1 then we only count numbers that contain both digits 0 and 1. i.e. the 10 counts, but the 1 doesn't because there's no 0.

Comment: General announcement
*****
Good number must contain all digits 0, 1, ..., k. this is really important...@Rup: count and main_count, where should i declare main_count inside the for loop or outside it..???

Comment: @Rup: I was suggested that a few minutes back, new to coding , noob's mistake.

Comment: If main_count is the total of the successful matched numbers, and you'll need the answer after the for loop, then yes you'll need to declare it outside.

Comment: if (counter==countdigits(N[j])) ?! N[j] is zero here!! because of N[j]=N[j]/10; and while condition

Comment: @Rup Variable length arrays were in C99. Welcome to the 21st century!

Comment: @Rup: that was exactly my question , appreciate the help.

Comment: I think you also forgot about a number that contain similar digits.

Comment: Hang on a minute: your code is checking that all digits in number `N[j]` are less than or equal to `k` (or it's trying too - Hasan's correct you're only ever calling countdigits on 0). That's not the problem: you need to make sure that all digits 0..k exist in the number.

Comment: @Rup: I know, saw the announcement later. That changed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  int n, k, count = 0;
  cin >> n >> k;
  while (n--)
  {
      cin >> s;
      int f[10] = {0};
      bool good = true;
      for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
          f[s[i]-'0']=1;

      for (int i=0;i<=k;i++)
          if (f[i]==0)
             good = false;
      if (good)
          count ++;
  }
  cout << count << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Accepted code on site. Trick was in "contains all digits not exceeding". problem description says that all numbers <= k must all be included. the problem didn't say that the numbers > k shouldn't be included. the fact that a digit greater than k exist or does not exist doesn't matter.